# minor error in if statement in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error notification point at my if statement that checks if the length > 0. Not sure what the reason is for this? Think it must be a very stupid curly bracket or something but just can't see it...

---

```
render() {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <div className="innercircleboxes">
                {
                    if(this.state.friends.filter(friend => (this.state.innerCircle).includes(friend._id)).length > 0){ 
                        this.state.friends.filter(friend => (this.state.innerCircle).includes(friend._id)).map(inner =>
                        <div key={inner._id}>
                            <InnerCircleDetail 
                                key={inner._id}
                                id={inner._id}
                                username={inner.username}
                                location={inner.location}
                            />
                        </div>
                        )    
                    }    
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `if` statements inside JSX. You must use **expressions**. Say the ternary operator

```
{a > b ? x : y}
```

Or in your case this would make more sense

```
{isTrue && <RenderMe/>}
```

Relevant [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).